# Laravel: sending JSONArray from ajax to Controller error: Undefined variable myData

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

I am sending a JSONArray via Ajax to Controller. and it is returning

> "500 Internal Server Error"

After checking response of URL in console I found that my Array is undefined:

> message- Undefined variable: myData
>
> exception- ErrorException
>
> file- C:\xampp\htdocs\EDO_Roster\app\Http\Controllers\EventController.php

This is my Ajax Code:

```
var myJson = JSON.stringify(myData);
      var button = document.getElementById("submit");
      button.addEventListener("click", function(event){

        $.ajax({
              headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
              },
              type: "POST",
              url: "{{route('postEvent' , 'myJson')}}",
              data: {myData:  myJson},
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
        }).done( function(data){
            console.log('Ajax was Successful!');
            console.log(data);
        }).fail(function(){
            console.log('Ajax Failed');
        });
      });
```

route of the function:

```php
Route::post('randomPost', 'EventController@postEvent')->name('postEvent');
```

This is my Controller Code

```php
public function postEvent(Request $request)
    {
        $events = DB::table('auto_events')
                ->insert(array(
                      'edo_id' => $myData->edo_id,
                      'strat' => $myData->start,
                      )
                    );

      return response($events, 200);          
    }
```

I've tried several solutions provided at stack overflow like changing Ajax calls, checked my route several times.

Comment: You're trying to access the $myData in function which is not defined you have to get the variable from $request i.e. $request->input('edo_id');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the variable `$myData` inside your controller, that's why you got that error on your controller, you're supposed to get the input data from `$request`

just try as below

```
public function postEvent(Request $request)
{
    $myData = $request->all();
    $events = DB::table('auto_events')
            ->insert(array(
                  'edo_id' => $myData->edo_id,
                  'strat' => $myData->start,
                  )
                );

  return response($events, 200);          
}
```

Comment: thanks this solves the problem but now i am having another error "Trying to get property 'edo_id' of non-object' " which i presume has something to do with JSON itself.

Comment: I think the `$request` variable contains array instead of object, can you try like this?
`'edo_id' => $myData['edo_id']`

Comment: array is like this: [{"id":1,"edo_id":4,"start":"2019-09-08"},{"id":2,"edo_id":2,"start":"2019-09-09"}]

Comment: ohh ok, that means you should add your insert query inside the loop